# Sort PHP multidimensional array based on child array value, then main array key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a PHP array like the following:

```
$array = array(
    '06930' => array(
        'count' => 20
    ),
    '06905' => array(
        'count' => 25
    ),
    '06910' => array(
        'count' => 15
    ),
    '06903' => array(
        'count' => 15
    ),
    '06920' => array(
        'count' => 10
    ),
    '06940' => array(
        'count' => 5
    ),
    '06915' => array(
        'count' => 10
    ),
);
```

Contains zip codes and some data (count, ...) related to that zip. I need to sort it based on count (DESC), and then sort it again based on zip code (ASC), so that the result will be as follows:

```
$array = array(
    '06905' => array(
        'count' => 25
    ),
    '06930' => array(
        'count' => 20
    ),
    '06903' => array(
        'count' => 15
    ),
    '06910' => array(
        'count' => 15
    ),
    '06915' => array(
        'count' => 10
    ),
    '06920' => array(
        'count' => 10
    ),
    '06940' => array(
        'count' => 5
    ),
);
```

Zip with bigger count will be above others, but if two zips have equal count, smaller zip will be above.

I can sort it based on count using:

```
uasort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return $b['count'] <=> $a['count'];
});
```

But can't sort based on zip afterwards.

I reviewed many similar questions and answers but still couldn't figure out how to sort second time by the main array key (zip).

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [array_multisort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

```
array_multisort(array_column($array,'count'), SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC,
                array_keys($array), SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_ASC,$array);
```

Output: -https://3v4l.org/QCrZf

Comment: Thank you! It worked as desired on my real array. Chose yours as answer because even though the other answers also worked -thank you too-, I prefer one-line solutions where possible.

Comment: @Envayo  glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can change it to use `uksort()` which gives you the keys to sort with, you will need to pass the array in as well (using `use`) so that it can access the values as well.

This checks if the counts are the same, if they are it will compare the keys instead...

```
uksort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($array) {
    if ( $array[$b]['count'] ==  $array[$a]['count'])   {
        return $a <=> $b;
    }
    return $array[$b]['count'] <=> $array[$a]['count'];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The short version of @Nigel Ren's answer:

```
uksort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($array) {
    return $array[$b]['count'] <=> $array[$a]['count'] ?: $a <=> $b;
});
```

Comment: I thought about shortening it, but I was worried that the shorter version also becomes harder to understand.

Comment: This is easier for me to understand and easier to expand.